# Adding user restrictions on who can edit posts in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to add restrictions on my site so that only the person who added a product or post can edit/delete that product or post. Currently, the edit button is visible to anyone so it's not ideal.

I've had a good crack at it, but something is still wrong as the edit button still shows up even when I'm not the post creator.

The **edit_forum_post** view I've created:

```
@login_required
def edit_forum_post(request, post_id):
    """ Create a view that allows us to edit a post """

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    registered_user = request.user.id
    creator = post.creator.id
    if not logged_user == creator:
        messages.error(request, 'You are unable to edit this post')
        return redirect('get_forum')

    if request.method == "POST":
        edit_post = ForumPostForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if edit_post.is_valid():
            edit_post.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully updated your post')
            return redirect('forum_post_details', post_id)

            edit_post = CreatePost(instance=post)

            context = {
                'form': edit_post,
                'post': post
            }
            return render(request, 'forum_post_form.html', context)
```

The clause I have added onto the **Edit post** button:

```
{% if registered_user == post.creator %}
        <a href="{% url 'edit_forum_post' post.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Edit Post</a>
{% endif %}
```

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably comparing an id with a `User` object, and that will not work. You can check if the `request.user.id` is the `post.creator_id` with:

```
{% if request.user.id == post.creator_id %}
    <a href="{% url 'edit_forum_post' post.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Edit Post</a>
{% endif %}
```

As for the view, you can make this faster by saving a query with:

```
@login_required
def edit_forum_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    if request.user.id != post.creator_id:
        messages.error(request, 'You are unable to edit this post')
        return redirect('get_forum')
    # …
```

Or you can even check this *in* the query you do to retrieve the `Post` object with:

```
@login_required
def edit_forum_post(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id, creator=request.user)
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Still hasn't worked for me, unfortunately. I've made the amendments to the view, but does anything need to be changed for the bottom section of the view? From **if request.method == "POST":** downwards?

Comment: @Jbenno97: can you print in the view what the `request.user.id` is and the `post.creator_id`? The `creator` is a `ForeignKey` to the user model?